# I have multiple TestRunParameters in an nunit .runsettings file. How can I loop over them?

Tags: c#, nunit, runsettings

I have a really simple .runsettings file for nunit that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
          <Parameter name="someParameterName" value="someExampleValue" />
          <Parameter name="variable1" value="someExampleValue" />
          <Parameter name="variable2" value="someExampleValue" />
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

What I am hoping to do is loop over the parameters instead of accessing by name.

This works if I only want a single value:

```
var value = TestContext.Parameters["someParameterName"];
```

It feels like this should work to loop over them but it doesn't:

```
var allParams = TestContext.Parameters;

foreach (var item in allParams) {
     //I'll want to get the items name and value here. 
}
```

I get this error:

> Compiler Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of
> type 'type1' because 'type2' does not contain a public definition for
> 'identifier'

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `TestContext.Parameters` returns `TestParameters`, which is not a collection.

The best you can do is:

```
var allParams = TestContext.Parameters;

foreach (var name in allParams.Names)
{
    //I'll want to get the items name and value here. 
    var value = allParams[name];
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} : {value}");
}
```

And the output will be like,

```
someParameterName : someExampleValue
variable1 : someExampleValue
variable2 : someExampleValue
```